# How to create audioContext from javascript's Audio class?

Tags: javascript, audio

I think the question title is very much representative of what I am trying to achieve, but to sum it up, I have an Audio object to play a base64 audio and would like to create an audioContext, which, it seems is only possible with the audio tag?

```
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/mp3;base64," + buffer);
```

Is there a way to create an audioContext from this object?